# Pass API Key to angular post

Tags: angular, authentication, http-headers

I have a login endpoint that need to pass like this. The username and pwd as a formdata.

[image]

auth.service.ts

```
 login(data: User) {
    var formData: any = new FormData();
    formData.append("username", data.username);
    formData.append("pwd", data.pwd);
    let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('token', '123456');
    return this.http.post(API_URL, { headers: new HttpHeaders({'token': '123456'})},formData);
  }
```

How I pass the authorization api key? I am getting error 404

Answer (score 1):

```
login(data: User) {
    var formData: any = new FormData();
    formData.append("username", data.username);
    formData.append("pwd", data.pwd);

    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
       'token', '123456'
      })
    };

  return this.http.post(API_URL,formData,httpOptions);
}
```